# Spring boot stops as I write some JPA queries in the repository

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, h2

I am using spring boot with H2 database. My application stops with below text on console.

```
2016-08-01 10:36:08.610  INFO 3920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.jpa.internal.util.LogHelper  : HHH000204: Processing PersistenceUnitInfo [
    name: default
    ...]
2016-08-01 10:36:08.651  INFO 3920 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate Core {4.3.11.Final}
2016-08-01 10:36:08.651  INFO 3920 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000206: hibernate.properties not found
2016-08-01 10:36:08.651  INFO 3920 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.cfg.Environment            : HHH000021: Bytecode provider name : javassist
2016-08-01 10:36:08.801  INFO 3920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {4.0.5.Final}
2016-08-01 10:36:09.031  INFO 3920 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.H2Dialect
2016-08-01 10:36:09.131  INFO 3920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.h.h.i.ast.ASTQueryTranslatorFactory    : HHH000397: Using ASTQueryTranslatorFactory
2016-08-01 10:36:09.291  INFO 3920 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000228: Running hbm2ddl schema update
2016-08-01 10:36:09.291  INFO 3920 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000102: Fetching database metadata
2016-08-01 10:36:09.301  INFO 3920 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000396: Updating schema
2016-08-01 10:36:09.311  INFO 3920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000261: Table found: TEST.PUBLIC.EMAILDATA
2016-08-01 10:36:09.311  INFO 3920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000037: Columns: [quantity, emailto, id, autostart, emailfrom]
2016-08-01 10:36:09.311  INFO 3920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
2016-08-01 10:36:09.311  INFO 3920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000126: Indexes: [primary_key_2]
2016-08-01 10:36:09.311  INFO 3920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000261: Table found: TEST.PUBLIC.STATUS
2016-08-01 10:36:09.311  INFO 3920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000037: Columns: [exchangefile, consolidate, processdate, aggregateall, scriptmaster, sendmail, id, insiderstrade]
2016-08-01 10:36:09.311  INFO 3920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000108: Foreign keys: []
2016-08-01 10:36:09.311  INFO 3920 --- [ost-startStop-1] o.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.TableMetadata   : HHH000126: Indexes: [primary_key_9]
2016-08-01 10:36:09.311  INFO 3920 --- [ost-startStop-1] org.hibernate.tool.hbm2ddl.SchemaUpdate  : HHH000232: Schema update complete
```

My repository is:

```
@Transactional
public interface EmailDataRepository extends JpaRepository<EmailData,Long>{
      @Query("SELECT p FROM EmailData P")
      public EmailData findLastRow();
}
```

And DBConfig is:

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("com.demo.*")
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
@EntityScan(basePackages = {"com.demo.model"})
@EnableJpaRepositories("com.demo.repository.main")
public class DBConfig {....}
```

Model:

```
@Entity
@Table(name="EmailData")
public class EmailData {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    Long id;
    private String emailTo;
    private String emailFrom;   
    private String quantity;
    private Boolean autoStart;
...}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `H2` database url should have the following configuration

```
DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE
```

Spring Boot documentation has a quote:

> If, for whatever reason, you do configure the connection URL for an embedded database, care should be taken to ensure that the database’s automatic shutdown is disabled. If you’re using H2 you should use DB_CLOSE_ON_EXIT=FALSE to do so. If you’re using HSQLDB, you should ensure that shutdown=true is not used. Disabling the database’s automatic shutdown allows Spring Boot to control when the database is closed, thereby ensuring that it happens once access to the database is no longer needed.